# Windows 10 refuses to boot

Tags: boot, windows-10, bootloader

Running Windows 10 upgrade on Windows 7 for months.  Gigabyte mobo, AMD processor.

Not sure when.  May have powered down without shutdown...

Windows 10 fails booting, displays the spinning dots then freezes.

- Booted using Windows 10 iso and tried repair - fails
- Booted Windows 10 iso and tried cmd line `bootrec /rebuildbcd` with tips found to 
  `bcdedit  /export c:\bcdbackup`

  `attrib c:\boot\bcd -h -r -s`

  `ren c:\boot\bcd bcd.old`
  [I am up to bcd.old5 now]

  `bootrec /rebuildbcd`
   
  did `bootrec /FixMBR /FixBoot`

  And it finds D:\Windows and I say `Y` it restarts -> same problem.

I even went in and copied the backup Registry hives over config directory.
Nothing seems to get this thing to boot.
I can go to D: and see that the entire Windows disk is there.
But I can't get this thing to boot!
Any more ideas?  Thanks!!!

I will give up and copy over files onto another disk.

Comment: Did you interrupt upgrade to Win 10 or you had already a running Win 10 which cannot boot anymore?

Comment: Win 10 had been running for some months.  I can boot to recovery cmd line and do a diskpart -> list volume and see C:  I can go to C:  and SEE the OS and user stuff.  How do I do these cmds to make it boot this?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try repair steps outlined in

[Fix - The drive where Windows is installed is locked](http://www.boyans.net/RepairWindows/The_drive_where_Windows_is_installed_is_locked.html)

(Assuming that you use either a recovery USB/DVD or Recovery on hard disk)

Execute **chkdsk** and **bcdboot** commands.

If still cannot boot after commands above you should try

offline repair of system files using **sfc** command.

Drive letters in commands should reflect mappings of partitions.

There is a "system" (**=active**) partition which contains boot files and a "boot" partition where Windows is installed, (note drive letters for those partitions and use them accordingly). If you don't have a separate "system" partition(System Reserved) then "system" and "boot" are Windows partition.

Comment: Thanks for help!  Did a "chkdsk C: /F"  --fixed a lot of files.  "diskpart-> list volume" lists D as system reserved NTFS 100MB, C no label, NTFS 465GB, E as no label, raw.    Did a "bcdboot D:\Windows /s D:"  but it says "failure when attempting to copy boot files"   ....  did I pick right disk?  Or do I have to do the bcdedit and atrib cmds above?   Thanks!

Comment: I was able to do a "bcdboot C:\Windows" --successful creation of boot files!   figuring out it needs to know where Windows files are....  I then rebooted and the OS started to come up, but after 3 or 4 sec the spinning dots freeze.  I guess I will have to repair some files using sfc?

Comment: Well, it booted into the spinning circles once, but the next time I got the 0x0000001 error.  File damage somewhere i guess.  running sfc from DVD

Comment: Whenever I boot DVD->cmd line, I have to run diskpart->list volume.  It seems to reverse the C: and the D: -> which is why cmds sometimes don't run!?  trying to get sfc /scannow /offbootdir=  /offwindir=

Comment: Had to learn how to del the pending.xml  to get past sfc.  I probably interrupted one.  offbootdir and offwindir are the same it seems...  usually c:    OK, I get to the spinning disks, they freeze, and on a reboot I get the 0xc000001 - guess that is the equivalent of the old "can't do this" but doesn't go into repeat mode, win10 stops here when it detects a bad boot.  No "start windows normally" option?  Back where I started.  Time to try a win "repair" I guess from the dvd. so close......

Comment: I am glad you made progress learning a lot. The main thing is to understand what is going on so you can easily localize the problem.

Comment: 0xc000001 means error in boot chain - either boot device is not specified properly or problem with winload.exe. Device(ApplicationDevice)+path specify full address of winload.exe. Use bcdedit to view values for device & path for the loader. You can set device using bcdedit.

Comment: bcdedit looks like a monster.  In first steps above I thot I saved BCD to c:\bcdbackup -- but I don't see it.  That would be my original bcd.  I also don't see my c:\boot\bcd.old2,3,4,5 exports...  I went to C:\boot and found a bcd - probably wrong one.  I went to D:\boot and no bcd.  SO I created it with "bcdboot c:\windows /s d:"  -- Now have bcd on d as well as c.  PC still boots exactly same - freezes 3,4 sec into spinning circle.  My "bcdedit [CR]" --prob wrong looks like this: which one is it reading?

Comment: WinbootMgr
identifier {bootmgr}
dev  partition=c:
desc  windows bootmgr
locale  en-us
inherit  {global settings}
default  {default}
resumeobject {UUID.....}
displayorder {default}
toolsdisplayorder {memdiag}
timeout  30
Windows Boot Loader
identifier {default}
dev  partition=c:
path  \Windows\system32\winload.exe
desc  windows10
locale  en-us
inherit  {boot loader setting}
allowmemsetting {0x15000075}
osdevice partition=c:
systemroot \windows
resumeobject {same UUID...}
nx  optin
bootmempolcy standard

Comment: I went into diskpart and made volume 2 (D:) active -- now there is an asterisk there.  Should boot from there, right?  Same symptom.  So bcd is screwed up someway.

Comment: Ready to abandon this windows....  can't run sfc on that file. Rebooted DVD, cmd line -> bcdbackup is on d:\ [where was it before?  I am using the /a:s and /a:h switches on dir] -> C and D are switched again.  Just for grins I I copied bcd to bcd.new and copied bcdbackup (original bcd) to bcd.  rebooted.....  0xc000001, DVD, cmd line, bcdedit --- looks nothing like the one above.  no UUIDs e.g. I am not learning anything here.  Linux is much more straightforward I think!

Comment: I found your boyans.net....  I will do some reading!   Looked at the BCD on my other win10 for ref.

Comment: I do have a system repair disk I created for that PC, but it was for win7.   I may try running it and see if it will work for Win10.  ........ I tried the system repair DVD and it REPEATED the failure  ---fails after spinning the dots for 3,4 sec.  I am losing my mind!

Comment: Save your user files (documents, images, other) to USB! Format disk. Reinstall Windows 10 using Windows 10 distribution media. Windows 10 will be activated automatically on a device it was installed earlier(you don't need key).

Comment: Thanks!  That is what I did.  Or I need to xfer files yet.  Thot I could just plug in the OLD SATA after win10 was all installed on new SATA disk and xfer over.  But PC hung up at AHCI init.....   Eventually got it back by clearing CMOS.  Not sure if I can plug that old disk in...  maybe some disk controller problem?  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: To "close out" this discussion....  Flaky behavior around SATA.  The only [new] constant is the hang up at "AHCI init" at boot, except first thing in the morning? Tried diff things in BIOS.  I think I have a flaky Southbride chip SB710 chip on mobo.  AM ordering a similar GByte mobo - hopefully win10 has a UUID or something embedded so it will accept the new mobo.